# tinyMCE and jQuery dialog box issue

Tags: jquery, tinymce

I am using TinyMCE inside of a jQuery dialog box.  To get the editor to work, I had to set the mode from "textareas" to "none". However doing that, makes the toolbar disappear.

This shows the toolbar, but the actual editing window does not works:

```
    tinyMCE.init({
    theme: "advanced",
    mode: "textareas",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_location: "top"
});
```

This causes the editing window to work, but the toolbar is missing:

```
    tinyMCE.init({
    theme: "advanced",
    mode: "none",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_location: "top"
});
```

Is there a way to get the toolbar back while having mode: "none"?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the second approach. The editor is not working there, but the textarea is.
What ouy still need to do is to init the editor using the `mceAddControl` action. Here is the code and a link to [a working tinymce fiddle](http://fiddle.tinymce.com/7zcaab/1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    tinyMCE.init({
    theme: "advanced",
    mode: "none",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_location: "top"
});
tinymce.execCommand('mceAddControl',false,'textarea_id' );
</script>

<form method="post" action="dump.php">
    <textarea id="textarea_id" name="content"></textarea>
</form>
```

Comment: Where and when do I add the 'tinymce.execCommand?  I added it and now the toolbar is there, but the editing window is readonly/nonworking. thanks

Comment: you need to make sure that your textarea is not hidden or invisible when you call the 'tinymce.execCommand'. It doesn't matter when you call this - it has to be after the tinymce init - that's all.